# Valores de script individuais dentro de um modal

Tags: php, javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal

Tenho um modal que apresenta um número e faço isso com ajuda de java script. Na minha página tenho uma pesquisa, e nos resultados percebi que somente o primeiro resultado aparece com o campo com a formatação correta assim: (00) 0000-0000.

Como posso fazer para que nos resultados o javascript posso entender cada script como individual?

Segue meu código:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.1.62/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
<!--Campo NUMERO-->
            <label for="numero" class="control-label" >
                <br>NÚMERO:<br></label>
            <div class="input-group col-lg-5">
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone" id="basic-addon-numero"></span>
                </div>
                <input type='text' id='numero' name='numero' value="<?php echo $numero ?>" class="form-control" maxlength='15' required autofocus placeholder="(00) 0000-0000"><br>
              <script>
              $(window).load(function()
              {
              var phones = [{ "mask": "(##) ####-####"}];
              $('#numero').inputmask({ 
              mask: phones, 
              greedy: false, 
              definitions: { '#': { validator: "[0-9]", cardinality: 1}} });
              });
            </script>
            </div>
            <!--Fim Campo NUMERO-->
```

Tenho um exemplo que uso, porém, como não sei muito de JavaScript não sei como adequar ao caso que perguntei.
Segue o exemplo que uso na moda e dá certo.

```html
<script>
 function mostrar1(e) {
  var tipo = e.parentNode.querySelector("[name='senha1']");
  if (tipo.type == "password") {
   tipo.type = "text";
   } else {
   tipo.type = "password";
  }
  
  tipo.type = tipo.type; //aplica o tipo que ficou no primeiro campo
  
  if (e.classList.contains("glyphicon-eye-open")) { //se tem olho aberto
   e.classList.remove("glyphicon-eye-open"); //remove classe olho aberto
   e.classList.add("glyphicon-eye-close"); //coloca classe olho fechado
   } else { //senão
   e.classList.remove("glyphicon-eye-close"); //remove classe olho fechado
   e.classList.add("glyphicon-eye-open"); //coloca classe olho aberto
  }
  
 }
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--Campo Senha-->
<form method="POST">
 <div class='input-group col-lg-6'>
  <div class='input-group-addon'>
   <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign'></span>
  </div>
 <input type='password' name='senha1' id="senha1" class='form-control' placeholder='Nova Senha' autofocus required></div>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open "
 onclick="mostrar1(this)"></button>
</form>
<!-- Script para ambos os botões -->
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Tentei fazer o que vc disse, porém, assim todos os campos ficam sem a mascara.

Comment: Essa mesma parte amigo.

Comment: Ele é só um, porém, está em um modal. Eu tenho um exemplo de um outro campo só que eu não sei utilizar nesse caso em específico. Eu vou colocar na pergunta

Comment: É uma página com resultado de uma pesquisa com vários resultados na tela abre um modal, ao acessar o primeiro resultado aparece tudo ok com o formato (00) 0000-0000, nas posteriores esse formato não funciona. Entendeu?

Comment: sim, mas vc não conseguirá aplicar a máscara a todos os campos usando `id`... tem que usar `class`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não use o mesmo `id` para vários elementos. Um `id` deve ser único na página. Assim o plugin irá pegar apenas o primeiro que achar e ignorar o restante.

Utilize `class="numero"` que o plugin irá aplicar a máscara a todos os elementos com essa classe:

```js
$(window).load(function(){
   var phones = [{ "mask": "(##) ####-####"}];
   $('.numero').inputmask({ 
   mask: phones, 
   greedy: false, 
   definitions: { '#': { validator: "[0-9]", cardinality: 1}} });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.1.62/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>

<input type='text' class='numero' name='numero' value="1234567890" class="form-control" maxlength='15' required autofocus placeholder="(00) 0000-0000"><br>
<input type='text' class='numero' name='numero' value="1234567890" class="form-control" maxlength='15' required autofocus placeholder="(00) 0000-0000"><br>
<input type='text' class='numero' name='numero' value="1234567890" class="form-control" maxlength='15' required autofocus placeholder="(00) 0000-0000"><br>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo aprendi ago que dá pra colocar dentro de uma class. Valeu!